# When instantiating a gameObject, my Z is set by default to -4000

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, instantiation

When I instantiate the game object inside my Canvas, its X and Y are set correctly, but my Z is set to -4000, making the game object invisible to the player. The "order in layer" of my canvas is 5.

What am I doing wrong?

```
// (...)

        private RectTransform rectTransform;
        private CanvasGroup canvasGroup;
        float spawnPositionX;
        float spawnPositionY;


    private void Awake() {
        
        rectTransform = GetComponent<RectTransform>();
        canvasGroup = GetComponent<CanvasGroup>();
        spawnPositionX = transform.position.x; //
        spawnPositionY = transform.position.y; //
    }

// (...)

    public void OnEndDrag(PointerEventData eventData) {

        Debug.Log("OnEndDrag");
        canvasGroup.alpha = 1f;
        canvasGroup.blocksRaycasts = true;

        GameObject iconSubs = Instantiate(gameObject, new Vector2(spawnPositionX, spawnPositionY), Quaternion.identity, GameObject.FindWithTag("Canvas").transform);
    }

// (...)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have some problems instantiate with a new Vector3(posx, posy, 0) and so if it's instantiating again with a z = -4000 than try to see the Z of the canvas. Sorting layer it's not important here

Comment: Instantiating with a new Vector3(spawnPosX, spawnPosY, 0f) doesn't change anything. The Z is still set by default as "-4000". And the Z of my canvas is 100;

Comment: Try to instantiate it without the canvas parent. What is happening?